# Dual booting Windows Server 2012 and Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I have a server I use for testing that currently has Server 2012 Standard. I need to do some testing with OpenLDAP so I shrunk the disk to have 500GB of free space and installed Ubuntu on it. Unfortunately when the restart phase occurred, the computer booted straight into Server 2012 without GRUB coming up and giving me the option to choose.

Is there a conflict between GRUB and the latest line of Windows operating systems? Or am I just doing something wrong? (I did make sure to put the boot loader onto the Ubuntu install partition instead of the install partition, as I have done in the past)

Answer (score 0):

Re-boot into the live environment of the ubuntu cd, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

The application that pops up will help you to reinstall the boot-loader, preferably to the MBR (/dev/sda).

Good Luck